# Create web report able to be exported in pdf

Tags: form

I'm new in the Craft CMS world, and I'm approaching it because I need to create a web app where I and my colleague can create reports based on what we do for customers and export them in PDF format.

Can I accomplish this task with Craft?

In positive case can anyone give me some hints about what to do to begin (example.. plugins to study etc..)

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad question since it does not cover a specific topic but many things about plugin development. I would suggest you to read articles like So [You Wanna Make a Craft 3 Plugin?](https://nystudio107.com/blog/so-you-wanna-make-a-craft-3-plugin) or [Enhancing a Craft CMS 3 Website with a Custom Module](https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module). You can create a boilerplate of a plugin with [Pluginfactory.io](http://pluginfactory.io).

To get used to the topic there are [official documentations](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/plugin-guide.html) as well. If you have specific problem/question you can ask it.

In general there aren't many things that can't be accomplished with Craft. It's a really dynamic and flexible CMS and can be enhanced/extended in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

A very broad question gets a very broad answer :)

You could use Craft for this (in various ways). Maybe these plugins can help you:

**PDF export plugins**

https://printmaker.docs.topshelfcraft.com/

https://github.com/enupal/snapshot

**Report plugin (CSV export)**

https://superbig.co/plugins/reports

There are others out there too that are probably worth a look.